# does deleting a record delete its full text index in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I am in charge of maintaining a horribly written application and database that has 11 million records in some tables.  I just recently optimized a query by adding a full text index.  However, I believe there is some arcane DTS package that actually drops the entire table that i am searching, pulls data from a linked server, and repopulates it.  my question is, when it deletes, truncates or drops the table, will the full-text have to get rebuilt, even though the table will get repopulated with almost the same data?  Or does the index get maintained completely separately?

--edit---

It definitely looks like what they are doing in the DTS is truncating the old table and reimporting everything.

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends whether the Changes Tracking is activated (set to AUTO) for this full-text index or not (set to MANUAL). In the latter case you need to manually rebuild your index and addition of new rows or deletions does not affect your index.

Comment: so if i have it on auto (I do) when it wipes the table, it wipes the FT indexing?  Also, see the edit i am adding.